# Get the User Id - SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a column that has names of the user. The column type is Single line of Text and the user name is stored in the format LastName, FirstName;

I would like to get the user id and email address of the stored user name.

I tried

```
 string fieldValue = item["ProjectManager"] as string;
 SPFieldUserValueCollection users = new SPFieldUserValueCollection(item.Web, fieldValue);
 if (users != null)
 {
     /* The users.count is always zero */
      foreach (SPFieldUserValue user in users)
      {
        if (user.User != null)
        {
        }
      }
   }
```

I cannot change the column type to Person or Group and it would remain as Single Line of Text. Please let me know how can I achieve this . I have been trying this for couple of hours now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public SPUser GetUser(SPWeb web, string userstring)
{
    var user = FetchUser(web, userstring);
    if (user == null)
    {
    SPPrincipalInfo info = SPUtility.ResolvePrincipal(web, userstring, SPPrincipalType.User, SPPrincipalSource.All, null, false);
    if (info!=null)
        user = FetchUser(web, info.LoginName);
    }
    return user;
}

public SPUser FetchUser(SPWeb web, string userstring)
{
    return web.AllUsers.Cast<SPUser>().FirstOrDefault(
    i => i.Name == userstring || i.LoginName == userstring || i.Email == userstring);
}
```

From SPUser you get get the user ID.

Get SPUser in your case with:

```
var user = GetUser(item.Web,fieldValue )
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Luis. I am getting the error SPUserCollection does not contain a definition for Cast for the line    return web.AllUsers.Cast<SPUser>().FirstOrDefault

Comment: You need to include the Linq namespace at the top: